# Connect to Wi-Fi router using SSID and WPS PIN on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I have a Wi-Fi router with a known WPS pin. How can I connect to this router using Android phone via Android API?

I've checked WiFiConfiguration Class in Android SDK manuals here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html and found no WPS parameters.

Comment: There's a WpsCallback in Lollipop (API 21). Might not help you.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the only way is to root the device and use wpa_cli calls.

Answer (score 0):

First root your device and download wps connect then click on network then click custom pin and write the pin of yur router and click connect . It will connect